# How to extract rows where a string matches?

Tags: regex, r

my data is as below and want to extract only those rows where data column has string like "7_" and its position is not fix. I wand to extract those rows where "7_" matches and data column should have only "7_" values.

```
Row No  Name  data
1       ABC    4_6035;9_47;7_113838;0_14
2       xyz    0_6035;7_145
3       MNO    4_6035;5_47;8_113838;7_14
4       PPP    0_6035;5_145 

Output I am looking for is 

Row No  Name  data
1       ABC    7_113838
2       xyz    7_145
3       MNO    7_14

Please help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
within(df[grep("7_", df$data, fixed = TRUE), ], 
       data <- sub(".*?(7_[^;]*).*", "\\1", data))
#   RowNo Name     data
# 1     1  ABC 7_113838
# 2     2  xyz    7_145
# 3     3  MNO     7_14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*\\b7_).*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/10